# Changing google map state in flutter using streambuilder

Tags: flutter

So I'm trying to change my map state using a StreamBuilder by retrieving the user location and adding a marker to the sink. This is my BLoC class:

```
class CustomMapBLoC {

  StreamController customMapStreamController = StreamController<Marker>.broadcast();
  Sink get customMapSink => customMapStreamController.sink;
  Stream<Marker> get customMapStream => customMapStreamController.stream;

  createMarker(MarkerId markerId, Position position) {
    Marker marker = Marker(
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      markerId: markerId,
      position: LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude),
    );
    customMapSink.add(marker);
  }

}
```

This is my StreamBuilder:

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: _customMapBLoC.customMapStream,
    builder: (context,snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.data != null) {
        _customMap.markersMap[_userPositionId] = snapshot.data;
        debugPrint("SNAPSHOT DATA: ${snapshot.data}"); // These two show the data is received in the console.
        debugPrint("MARKERSMAP: ${_customMap.markersMap}");
      }
      return _customMap; //_customMap is created inside the build method
    },
),
```

And this is where I call the createMarker method:

```
FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      _getPositionSubscription = geolocator.getPositionStream().listen((Position currentLocation) {
        _customMapBLoC.createMarker(_userPositionId, currentLocation);
      });
    },
)
```

This is how I pass the markers map I'm changing in the _customMap class:

```
static Map<MarkerId, Marker> _markersMap = <MarkerId, Marker>{};

CustomMap(): super(
    mapType: defaultMapType,
    initialCameraPosition: defaultCameraPosition,
    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
      _mapControllerCompleter.complete(controller);
    },
    markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markersMap.values),
);
```

Why isn't this working? What I'm doing wrong?

This piece of code, using a Firebase stream seems to be working and my own stream doesn't.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection("users").where("type",isEqualTo: 2).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.data.documents.length > 0) {
        debugPrint("MARKERS: ${_customMap.markersMap}");
        for(var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
          MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(snapshot.data.documents[i]['uid']);
          Marker marker = new Marker(
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
            markerId: markerId ,
            position: LatLng(34.040501,-4.9898821),
          );
          _customMap.markersMap[markerId] = marker;
        }
      }
      return _customMap;
    },
)
```

EDIT: Here is the full build method code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CustomMap _customMap = CustomMap();
    _customMapBLoC = new CustomMapBLoC();
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBarLayout(context,"Home",scaffoldKey) ,
      drawer: DrawerLayout(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: _customMapBLoC.customMapStream,
            builder: (context,snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.data != null) {
                _customMap.markersMap[_userPositionId] = snapshot.data as Marker;
                debugPrint("SNAPSHOT DATA: ${snapshot.data}");
                debugPrint("MARKERSMAP: ${_customMap.markersMap}");
              }
              return _customMap;
            },
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment(1.0, 1.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 35,
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _getPositionSubscription = geolocator.getPositionStream().listen((Position currentLocation) {
                        _customMapBLoC.createMarker(_userPositionId, currentLocation);
                      });
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.location_off,
                      size: 16,
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xffF2AB64),
                  )
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: there is no `addMarker` method in your code

Comment: @pskink just a typo, it's createMarker

Comment: is `_customMapBLoC.createMarker` called at all? tried to add some `print('createMarker called')` and check the logs?

Comment: @pskink Yes, it's called. In my `StreamBuilder` I have a `debugPrint` to see if I'm receiving any data. It's printed in the console but the map doesn't seem to be updated.

Comment: so what is not working? you press `FloatingActionButton` then `createMarker` is called and finally `StreamBuilder` is rebuilt (its `builder: (context, snapshot)` is called) - so whats wrong in it? the `snapshot` is wrong or what?

Comment: My object `_customMap` is an instance of a class that inhertis GoogleMap class. In its constructor I pass the `markers` property. When the StreamBuilder is rebuilt, the markers map I have in my class is updated, thus the widget has to be updated as well. The map would show a marker on it using a normal setState() with the button click. But using this StreamBuilder doesn't add any marker, as if the map didn't even rebuilt itself. And awkwardly using a different stream (Firebase for example) does add the marker.

Comment: ok you are returning `_customMap;` from the builder - where is `_customMap = ...` inside the builder? i only see `_customMap.markersMap[markerId] = ...` but there is no creation code? just post your complete code

Comment: My `StreamController` is of type `Marker`, so I don't have to do something like `_customMap = new value`, I only do `_custom.markersMap[markerId] = new marker` since the data I'm changing isn't the map itself but the markers property in the map.

Comment: where is `_customMap = ...` part in your code? where do you initialize `_customMap`?

Comment: Inside the build method (where the StreamBuilder is).

Comment: no, i dont see it inside the `StreamBuilder`'s builder - just add: `_customMap = ...; `before `for(var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {`

Comment: Not the builder, the StatefulWidget build method, I edited the in original post

Comment: The code you're quoting isn't the one not working. Please read my original post carefully.

Comment: StreamBuilder(
            stream: _customMapBLoC.customMapStream,
            builder: (context,snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.data != null) {
`CustomMap _customMap = CustomMap();`                _customMap.markersMap[_userPositionId] = snapshot.data as Marker;
                debugPrint("SNAPSHOT DATA: ${snapshot.data}");
                debugPrint("MARKERSMAP: ${_customMap.markersMap}");
              }
              return _customMap;
            },
          ),

Comment: `"so I don't have to do something like _customMap = new value"` yes, you have to create `CustomMap` inside your `StreamBuilder`

Comment: Why is that? Using the Firebase stream I'm not creating the map inside the builder and it works fine. What's the difference here?

Comment: did it work? i didnt see you firebase code so what can i say?

Comment: It worked, but it takes a few seconds to show up.

Comment: no, it does not take any seconds - you have some other bug - creating new `Widget`s is very cheap in flutter

Comment: Check my answer below, and tell me what I'm failing to notice here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not ideally the right answer as it's not entirely logical. But creating my map inside the builder method seems to be working. The marker also seems to be taking around 5 seconds to show up. Even when the debugPrint shows the data almost instantly as I click the button.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: _customMapBLoC.customMapStream,
    builder: (context,snapshot) {
      CustomMap _customMap = CustomMap(); // This is the newly added line
      if(snapshot.data != null) {
        _customMap.markersMap[_userPositionId] = snapshot.data as Marker;
        debugPrint("SNAPSHOT DATA: ${snapshot.data}");
        debugPrint("MARKERSMAP: ${_customMap.markersMap}");
      }
      return _customMap;
    },
),
```

However, using the same with a different stream. In this case a Firebase store snapshot works without having to create the map inside the builder method.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection("users").where("type",isEqualTo: 2).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.data.documents.length > 0) {
        debugPrint("MARKERS: ${_initMap.markersMap}");
        for(var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
          Marker marker = new Marker(
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
            markerId: _markerId,
            position: LatLng(34.040501,-4.9898821),
          );
          MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(snapshot.data.documents[i]['uid']);
          _initMap.markersMap[markerId] = marker;
        }
      }
      return _initMap; //This object is created outside the builder method
    },
),
```

Comment: I added a print after the object creation and before the return (the first in the Widget Build method and the second in the Stream Builder method). And the result was this: `I/flutter ( 4763): Builder Method: 272475105` and `I/flutter ( 4763): Build Method: 25156775`, apparently they're not the same objects, but I haven't made any changes to the object itself in the builder method, how is this happening?